# Проблема с MediaElement

Tags: c#, wpf

Вопрос такой, я всё делаю правильно, но, почему-то то что я пытаюсь сделать, даже не отображается в проекте.
Коротко о нём:
Я пытаюсь сделать чтобы картинка, она же gif, начала работать, суть её в том, что она просто крутится.

Не понимаю в чём проблема собственно.
Скриншот:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Я вам очень сильно советую перейти на векторную графику (например можете поставить [это](https://github.com/charri/Font-Awesome-WPF/blob/master/README-WPF.md)), ибо gif/png/jpg и ресурсов потребляют больше, и плохо дружат с масштабированием. Ну а так, `MediaElement` очень ограничен (особенно в Framework), ответом на ваш вопрос будет [файл мультимедиа нельзя использовать как ресурс](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/desktop/wpf/graphics-multimedia/multimedia-overview).

Comment: @EvgeniyZ  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ug5tc7zMJsM&t=199s Вот парень спокойно использует, хотя я делал всё по его уроку, у него в итоге получилось, у меня же нет...

Comment: А теперь смотрим на 3:04 и видим, что он делает то, о чем я вам говорил. Ну а вообще, не очень хороший "гайд" вы выбрали, для понимания WPF может и норм, но как основа я бы вам не советовал.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ Дело не в том что я там выбрал, просто я пытаюсь заставить себя кодить, хотя бы так, НО, повторяя за ним, в чёткости 100 % у него по итогу всё работает, а у меня нет, вот и вопрос, почему так?

Comment: Вы издеваетесь? Я вам сказал первым комментарием что? `файл мультимедиа нельзя использовать как ресурс.`, даже ссылку привел. где написано `файл мультимедиа нельзя использовать как ресурс проекта. Вместо этого в файле проекта необходимо выбрать тип мультимедиа Content и задать для CopyToOutputDirectory значение PreserveNewest или Always.`, у вас `CopyToOutputDirectory` вон даже на скрине, какое значение имеет? Также я вам дал точное время на видео, где автор делает нужное вам, а вы вместо того, чтоб сверить, уперто настаиваете на своем, что "100% делаете по гайду".

Comment: @EvgeniyZ Я опять же дико извиняюсь, я сделал всё так как вы говорите, и из этого ничего не получается. [Картинка](https://imgur.com/9qlSC7M) Я попробовал все возможные методы, и из этого ничего не выходит

Comment: Зачем вам `/` в начале пути? Ведь даже в вашем видео автор убирает его (3:10). А вообще, когда вы говорите "не работает", делайте минимальный пример, чтоб можно было воспроизвести у себя. Я например сделал [следующее](https://i.imgur.com/GMR2HSf.png), как видите, все успешно отрабатывает.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ Я делаю так-же как и вы, и всё равно не получается... хотя использовал только что совершенно разные гифки... [Тестовый проект](https://disk.yandex.ru/d/BFvriGjT7EtepA)

Comment: Не, ну точно издеваетесь, ибо я не знаю как [это](https://i.imgur.com/I3HgJtN.png) еще объяснить...

Comment: @EvgeniyZ Я честно говоря и сам не до конца понял почему так происходит: [Видео](https://imgur.com/6Duuttg)

Comment: Я не знаю, пробуйте пересобрать проект, пробуйте удалить папки `obj` и `bin` и после пересобирать, пробуйте студию перезапускать, пробуйте вообще компьютер перезапустит, честно, тут я уже без понятия что у вас, ибо как видите, я на ваших глазах распаковал то, что вы мне дали, запустил, удалил лишь `/` в начале и все успешно отобразилось.